# Host multiple sites in nginx digital ocean

Tags: nginx, devops, digital-ocean

I created digital ocean droplet and host a RESTapi. In the same droplet now I need to host two different vuejs SPAs. I install nginx and I don't know what to next. I gothough some tutorials and they say goto `/etc/nginx/conf.d/virtual.conf`  and edit `virtual.conf` But there is no such a file there and also some tutorials say goto `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` and edit the default file.
What should I do?

Hope you understand my question.

Answer (score 0):

I have always created virtual host site files in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/`
and then symlinked them to `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`

You can either have only one site file with multiple server blocks or multiple site files with only one server block. I think the latter is best practice.

For a complete guide, visit [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-server-blocks-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-16-04) tutorial

Comment: /etc/nginx/sites-available/ has a file called default. There I changed the default server block and host a one app as default one for the port 80. If I copy this server block and paste right after that and set the port to some thing like 9050 will that work?

Comment: Do you want both port 80 and port 9050 listening for this host, or only 9050? 
You dont necessarily need the default port 80 server block, you could just replace it with 9050 @PathumSamararathna